# Получение всех файлов в папке проекта UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

При разработке приложения появилась необходимость в использовании иконок для приложения. Планируется использовать более 50-ти иконок. И чтобы не прописывать путь в ручную к каждой было принято решение получить сразу все картинки как файлы `GetFiles()` следующим образом:

```
string path = $"{new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets\Images\Some")}";
//path == "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/Some"
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles();
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> System.IO.IOException: "Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома : 'C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\TestUWP\TestUWP\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\ms-appx:\Assets\Images\Some'"

Соответственно: `Directory.Exists(path) //false`

Хотелось бы заметить что при использовании другого пути `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` есть возможность выполнить скрипт без ошибки, а также что при использовании такого же пути для задания источника картинки, ошибок не выдаёт:

```
BitmapImage map = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets\Images\Some\41-11-22-194133.png"));
```

**Вопрос**: Как мне получить все файлы с папки при условии что папка находиться внутри проекта?

Comment: А папка `ms-appx:` точно существует? Это больше похоже на пространство имен.  Иконки не нужно загружать ни из каких папок, их можно добавить в [ресурсы проекта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files)

Comment: А если по существу вопроса - `new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory)` - это то, где лежит экзешник, есть свойство `Parent`. Дальшe: `Path.Combine(ParentPath, "Images\Some")` и вот вам папка в которой ваши изображения. Алгоритм очень грубо показан, но я думаю понятна суть

Comment: @Aarnihauta ваш совет мне действительно помог. У меня получилось добраться этим путём до нужных файлов. Насчёт `ms-appx` я не уверен, с помощью этого пути у меня получалось добираться до конкретных файлов но не к папкам.